# Javascript if/else statement for hide/show divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, if-statement

I have two divs that are hidden from view until corresponding image links are clicked on. As is, both divs can be shown at the same time by clicking on one and then the other and I do not want this. I am trying to write an if statement that says if one has been clicked on the other will not display, but I have had no luck. Here is the javascript I am up with that does not work:

```
 $("#about").click(function () {
    if ($("#aboutdetails").fadeIn("slow") == 'true') {
    $("#contact").css({'display': 'none'});
    }
$("#aboutdetails").click("slow",function () {
        $(this).hide();     
    });
});


$("#contact").click(function () {
    if ($("#contactdetails").fadeIn("slow") == 'true') {
    $("#about").css({'display': 'none'});
    }
$("#contactdetails").click("slow",function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

and here is the original code before I attempted the if statement:

```
 $("#about").click(function () {
    $("#aboutdetails").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $("#aboutdetails").click("slow",function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});


$("#contact").click(function () {
   $("#contactdetails").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $("#contactdetails").click("slow",function () {
           $(this).hide();
        });
   });
});
```

neither are very eloquent as I am still learning!

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two different divs named "div1" and "div2" with links "link1" and "link2"...

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
    $('#div1').show();
    $('$div2').hide();
});

$('#link2').click(function() {
    $('#div2').show();
    $('$div1').hide();
});
```

Is that what you are trying to do?  Click on link1 -> show div1, hide div2. Click on link2 -> show div2 hide div1?

I'm not sure if that is what you wanted. If not please try and clarify your question.

Edit with code example from your site: Try this

```
$("#about").click(function () {
  $("#aboutdetails").fadeIn("slow", function() {

  });
  $("#contactdetails").hide();
});


$("#contact").click(function () {
$("#contactdetails").fadeIn("slow", function() {

});
$("#aboutdetails").hide();
});

$("#aboutdetails").click(function() {
   $("#aboutdetails").hide();
});
 $("#contactdetails").click(function() {
    $("#contactdetails").hide();
});
```

Comment: M. Laing: yes exactly that is what I am trying to accomplish...I will try these suggestions and be back in a moment. Thanks

Comment: if div1 is visible and you click on link1, did you want it to hide div1 or just stay open? That code I gave will make it just stay open..

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but I am no longer able to close the div's by clicking inside of them-- I was using jquery.min.js to accomplish this...I have tried to adjust your code to implement this, but no luck

Comment: Just a moment...I am getting an error on that last one...trying to find the problem

Comment: I fixed it...thank you so much...looks and works wonderfully! I added an edit to your code

Comment: Good I'm glad I could help.  If the code in my answer is the final answer to your question mark it as the right solution so other's can find help from it later on.

Comment: I would be happy to, but I do not see where to do so? I clicked on the up arrow, but it says I need more reputation

Comment: It's not the up arrow... normally there is like a checkbox

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/utijaq/1/edit)*

Actually... it would be much simpler to use `classes` (e.g: `.box`) for your contents, and `ID`s only for your buttons:

```
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="about">ABOUT</li>
    <li id="contact">CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="box aboutdetails">
    About details here..........
  </div>
  
  <div class="box contactdetails">
    Contact details here..........
  </div>
```

Than all you need is:

```
$('#nav li').click(function(){              // any li 'button'
  $('.box').hide();                         // hide opened
  $('.'+this.id+'details').fadeIn(600);     // this.id will take the button's ID
});
```

What this script does is:

- On any button click hide all `.box`
- register the ID (`this.id`) of the clicked button and search for the element that has a class named like the button `ID` + `details`

Nice huh?

Comment: Thanks, Roko. I am trying to stick with what I already have by implementing M. Laing's ideas. I think we are close to nailing it:)

Comment: @user1505573 http://jsbin.com/utijaq/4/edit This will allow you to hide the opened one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the other one is visible, using:

```
$('#blabla').is(':visible')
```

It will return *true* or *false*;

Answer (score 0):

this is a tricky question since you are dealing with click events that will be triggered when clicked and you dont have control on when user clicks on the divs, however what you can do is toggle the if the user clicks on one it make it visible and hides other.

here is the code for it

```
$("#about").click(function () {
 $("#aboutdetails").fadeIn("slow", function() {
  $("#contactdetails").hide();
  $("#aboutdetails").click("slow",function () {
   $(this).hide();
 });
 });
});


$("#contact").click(function () {
   $("#contactdetails").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $("#aboutdetails").hide();
    $("#contactdetails").click("slow",function () {
     $(this).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: try this: `$("#about").click( aboutHandler);
$("#contact").click(contactHandler);

function aboutHandler(event evt){
    $("#contactdetails").hide();
 $("#aboutdetails").fadeIn("slow");
 $("#aboutdetails").click(function () {
 $(this).hide();
 });
}

function contactHandler(event evt){
    $("#aboutdetails").hide();
 $("#contactdetails").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $("#contactdetails").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
 });
}`